# How to symbolize chrome browser heap dump to analyze memory leak

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I'm trying to analyze a memory leak in our web application. So, I am trying to follow the steps mentioned in the link https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/memory-infra/heap_profiler.md to generate heap dump of chrome and analyze it.

I'm stuck at step 4 of 'How to obtain a heap dump (M66+, Linux, macOS, Windows)' section where I have to symbolize the trace/dump. I'm trying out the 'Windows only' option of Step 4. Does anybody know what does the statement 'For subsequent commands, add the flag --addr2line-executable=' mean?

Comment: Apparently it refers to `symbolize_trace` commands in the next paragraphs.

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry but can you provide more details? I have the heap dumps generated(around 5 dumps taken over different intervals) and also built the addr2line-pdb project from chromium repository. I'm not getting what command I should run to symbolize the dumps/traces.